# Async CTP installed Ok but nowhere to be found?

Tags: c#-4.0, installation, async-ctp

I installed the Async CTP Refresh on my Windows 7 machine with VS2010 Pro(which already had the WP7.0 (not Mango) dev tools installed) and even though it said it installed OK it is just not there!!

According to my other dev machine that has the same setup the ASync CTP is in 
C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP but on the machine I just installed on that folder does not exist and there is nothing in the start menu / all programs.

Here's what I have installed :

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Installed Version: Professional

Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Microsoft Visual Basic 2010

Microsoft Visual C# 2010

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Explorer

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010

Microsoft Windows Phone Developer Tools - ENU

Crystal Reports Templates for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB983509)   KB983509

Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 Build 4.0.20823.0

Anyone know what the problem nmight be?  It installed 100% OK on my other machine which runs pretty much identical dev tool set so I am mystified as to what's happened!
As far as I know I don't have ASP MVC 3 installed as I don't really do web development so I doubt it's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually a bit embarrassed as I realised it had installed in the My Documents on my D: drive and I was looking for the default install in C:\My Documents!

I do wish MS would offer us to choose the install folder with these tools though!